# How to ignore non-serializable properties from being cached using Akavache?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, akavache

I have a custom class to be cached using Akavache. This class contains one non-serializable property (it's a ParseFile object). When I try to cache/get a list of this custom class using GetAndFetchLatest, it doesn't work. I figure it may be caused by one property that is non-serializable. Tried JsonIgnore attribute, but didn't help.

Question is, how can I tell Akavache to cache everything in the list of custom class, except the non-serializable property? Sample of the custom class is here, I want it to ignore the Photo property:

```
[ParseClassName("User")]
public class User : ParseObject
{
    [ParseFieldName("name")]
    public string Name
    { 
        get { return GetProperty<string>(); }
        set { SetProperty<string>(value); }
    }

    [ParseFieldName("photo")]
    public ParseFile Photo
    { 
        get { return GetProperty<ParseFile>(); }
        set { SetProperty<ParseFile>(value); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[DataContract]` and `[IgnoreDataMember]` to prevent fields to be serialized

Comment: It still doesn't work :( Probably because Akavache isn't using System.Runtime.Serialization to serialize it.

Comment: JSON.NET respects System.Runtime.Serialization attributes, are you sure you marked your class with `DataContract` *and* all the members?

Comment: I did, this below code is what I did. But it doesn't look like the User class is cached even after this modification.

`[DataContract]
[ParseClassName("User")]
public class User
{
    [DataMember]
    [ParseFieldName("name")]
    public string Name
    { 
        get { return GetProperty<string>(); }
        set { SetProperty<string>(value); }
    }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [ParseFieldName("photo")]
    public ParseFile Photo
    { 
        get { return GetProperty<ParseFile>(); }
        set { SetProperty<ParseFile>(value); }
    }
}`

Comment: By the way, Akavache uses Sqlite3 as its backend.

Comment: What is this "GetProperty" and "SetProperty" business?

Comment: It's the format used to obtain data from Parse database. See https://parse.com/docs/dotnet_guide#subclasses-properties. Maybe it has something to do with the serialization too? I don't know, but all other Parse subclasses that does not have ParseFile property is able to be cached properly.

Comment: Your answer is probably correct. The reason why it didn't work in my case is because ParseObject itself is non-serializable (I just found out!), meaning I can't serialize the whole thing, not only the 'Photo' property. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: It should be simply      [Ignore] , have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

The default Json.Net behavior is to serialize all public fields and properties except those marked with the [JsonIgnoreAttribute] attribute.
ref: http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/10/23/efficient-json-with-json-net-reducing-serialized-json-size